# I updated opencart module from 1.5.6.4 to 2.0.0.0. Admin part of module is working fine. But the catalog controller is not working

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart, opencart2.x

I updated opencart module from version 1.5.6.4 to version 2.0.0.0. Admin controller is working fine but catalog controller is not working. I am not getting any output.

Comment: What is the problem in the catalog controller,will expalain a bit??

Comment: There is no "admin" controller. There are probably 50 or more "controllers" in the admin area. Are you referring to the `admin/controller/catalog` controllers or the `catalog/controller/*` controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not configured in preferred layouts.

Following message will be shown after u configured module settings.

" **After you have installed and configured a module you can add it to a layout here!**"

In that above message "here" is a link. just click on "here". It will redirect you to layouts page.

And then configure home page layout from that layout options.

i think this is the only thing u must be missed. otherwise there is something wrong in your module coding.